# Where is catalog helper declared?

Tags: magento

I cannot find any declaration in the config or other files.

I tried to find smth like:

```
<helpers>
   <catalog>
      <class>Mage_Catalog_Helper</class>
   </catalog>
</helpers>
```

But there are no any entry even Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image.

Could someone to help to find it?

Comment: The code file is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data.php`

Comment: But there are not any definition of image. I think it could be some method like $this->helper("catalog/$callHelper"); but there are not some similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The autoloader cheats. If it cannot find a definition for an alias (eg. `"catalog"`) then it assumes it must be a `Mage` module. You can put in any unknown alias and see the same thing happen. For example calling:

```
Mage::getModel('foo/bar');
```

...produces an error like:

> Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Foo_Model_Bar' not found

That is why you cannot find the catalog helper declaration; there is none. But you can create your own and it will take precedence.

Comment: +1. The "cheating" happens at `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()`